# vuejs2 splice remove only last element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hi im trying to remove element from array in vuejs2
and this is my html code

```
<tr class="o_data_row o_selected_row" v-for='(line , id) in lines'>
    <td>anything here</td>
    <td class="o_list_record_remove" style='width:10%'>
        <button @click='remove_line(id)' class="fa fa-trash-o" name="delete"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and this is my vuejs2 code

```
remove_line:function(index)
{
    console.log(index);
    console.log(this.lines);
    this.lines.splice(index,1);
}
```

in console i gat correct index and the lines also is correct .. 
i dont know whats wrong with the code thanks a lot ..

[image]

Comment: Could you include a description of what actually happens?

Comment: ive edited the post with screen shot

Comment: OK, it looks like you just need to provide a suitable `key` for the `<tr>` elements. Currently they're being keyed by the default index and that won't pair them up correctly after an item is removed. Without knowing more about you data it's difficult to speculate about what a suitable `key` might be but it must not be the index in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use some unique prop for each element in the 'lines' array not an index.
2. Add this unique prop to :key where v-for is located like this:

```
<tr class="o_data_row o_selected_row" v-for='(line , id) in lines' :key="line.uniq_prop">
```

3. Pass the lines item in the remove_line function like this:

```
<button @click='remove_line(line)'
```

4. In the remove_line find an element's index that is about to delete and splice it:

```
remove_line:function(line)
{
    console.log(line);
    console.log(this.lines);
    const index = this.lines.indexOf(line);
    this.lines.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: same result delete the last element

Comment: add console.log(index) after const index = this.lines.indexOf(line); and write a result here

Comment: i gat the index of the required element

Answer (score 1):

```
<button v-on:click="lines.splice(id, 1)" class="fa fa-trash-o" name="delete"></button>
```

or

```
<button @click.prevent='remove_line(id)' class="fa fa-trash-o" name="delete"></button>
```